# Inserting an element with pointer to std::map using Index operator

Tags: c++, data-structures, std

Say I have an std::map type which for example is defined as follows.

```
std::map<int, int>* someMap;
```

If I weren't using a pointer, I could simply add an element using the index operator. However in this case, since I have a pointer, would the following be the correct way to insert using the index operator.

```
(*someMap)[someIndex] = someValue;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The `operator []` is overloaded for the `Map` class. It has to be used directly with the object.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you *point* `someMap` at something. Otherwise, its just contains a meaningless address derived from garbage on the stack. Here's an example allocating from the heap:

```
  std::map<int, int>* someMap = new std::map<int, int>();
```

and once thats done, yes, you are correct in how to use it:

```
  (*someMap)[someIndex] = someValue;
```

and be sure to cleanup after yourself

```
  delete someMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is fine:

```
(*someMap)[someIndex] = someValue;
```

Comment: Why shouldn't I call like `somemap->[someIndex] = someValue`? Why it should be directly called with object restricting the pointer?